# Wordpress - How to display original featured Image Size in Post

Tags: wordpress, slider, custom-post-type

I have created custom Post type "slider". The problem I am having is It is not displaying the original picture size in the slider.
Here's my code

```
 <?php 

              $options = array(
            'post_type' => "slideshow",

    );  
            $my_query = new WP_Query($options);


          while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post(); 

            if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
     $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( the_ID()));
}?>
          <div data-thumb="<?php echo $image[0];?>"
          data-src="<?php echo $image[0];?>">


            </div>

            <?php endwhile; ?>
```

Comment: I edited my answer, the parameter `full` is supported, that's the original image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [docs](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_post_thumbnail#Post_Thumbnail_Linking_to_large_Image_Size), you could pass the parameter `large` to the `wp_get_attachment_image_src` function:

```
wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id(), 'full' );
```

The problem with this is that checking the [source code](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.0/src/wp-includes/media.php#L657) for this function seem to be a limitation in the size of the image.